# laravel api with vue 2 js not returning data - could 'localhost:8000' (or '127.0.0.1:8000') be the issue?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I am using the repo https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/laravel-ng2-vue/tree/03-vue-frontend so I have 100% confidence in the reliability of the code.  I can post through the laravel api endpoint through the very simple Vue client, and also through Postman.  Through Postman I can retrieve the table data array, but not so in the client app.  In POSTMAN:

```
localhost:8000/api/quotes
```

works just fine.

IN THE  vue 2 js CLIENT APP:

```
methods: {
        onGetQuotes() {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/quotes')
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.quotes =  (response.data.quotes);
                    }     
                )
                .catch(
                    error => console.log(error)
                );
        }
```

returns nothing.  returning the response to Console.log returns nothing.  The Network/XHR tab shows the table data rows, but I am not sure what that means.

I know for sure that this code works for others with their unique api endpoints, which I assume may not use localhost or '127:0.0.1:1080.

Edit: in response to request for more info

```
public function getQuotes()
{
    $quotes = Quote::all();
    $response = [$quotes];
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

and the relevant route:

```
Route::get('/quotes', [
    'uses' => 'QuoteController@getQuotes'
]);
```

Just to confirm: I am using verified github repo code in which the ONLY change is my api endpoint addressas mentioned in the first line of the body of this question.   .  Note that the Laravel back end is also derived from a related repo in Max's fine tutorial. The running code can be seen at

So I really don't think this is a coding error- but is it a configuration error due to me using local host??

EDIT: **It WAS a coding error** in the laravel controller as shown below

Comment: try to ping the localhost and let us know what you get.

Comment: If you add console.log(response.data) what do you get? Also, would be able to show your Controller method for this route?

Comment: @prosti Yes, I can ping the port whether or not I am running php artisan serve (laravel's built in server).  I may be wrong but is it not implied that the api is accessible as I can Post and Get through Postman?  And I can create (Post) through the vue app to the laravel api?  The only thing I cannot get the vue app to return the data array.

Comment: @Ross Wilson - bin there, done that - no data array object returned with console.log either (even though on the chrome developer tools tab - Network/XHR - it does show data being returned (don't know anything about this tab or the significance of this.

If the laravel controller wasn't working Postman would not return data, but here it is:
    
    Route::get('/quotes', [
        'uses' => 'QuoteController@getQuotes'
    ]);

Comment: I was only asking if you could show that as I thought I could possibly help you debug it. No worries though.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion - it really is a mystery seeing how I'm using such solid code.  Have you created a vue 2 js client app with a laravel back end on a local host dev environment? Maybe that's how I should pose my question rather than people thinking it might be a coding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working if because you haven't provided a key for your `$quotes` in your controller but you're looking for it in your vue file (`response.data.quotes`).

`[$quotes]` is essentially `[0 => $quotes]` so when the json response comes through it be `0: [...]` not `quotes: [...]`.

To get this to work you just need to change:

```
$response = [$quotes];
```

to:

```
$response = ['quotes' => $quotes];
```

---

Furthermore, just an FYI, you don't need to provide the `200` in `response->json()` as it's the default and you can just return an array and `Laravel` automatically return the correct json response e.g.:

```
public function getQuotes()
{
    $quotes = \App\Models\Artist::all();

    return compact('quotes'); //<-- This is just another way of writting ['quotes' => $quotes]
}
```

Obviously, you don't have to if you don't want to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was the answer! The only part of the project that was not in github, and the only part that I did not check. typical user error - went back to review the video portion that covered this and it was my oversight.

Comment: @ Ross Wilson 
I think I never bothered to check the controller thoroughly is because Postman was returning the full array.  I'm not clever enough to figure that one out.